# load js depending on url

Tags: node.js, express

I'm sure this question has been asked many a time before but I am having zero luck finding my 'question'.

I'm trying to figure out what the best solution is to loading a js file dynamically depending on the page/url. Should I handle this in controllers?

Am I right in assuming I should be using something like Browserify or requireJS? I do not understand how they are used in this manner, though...

I'm using Expressjs

I had something like this...

```
assets = {
  js: {
    validation: 'path/to/file'
  } 
}
```

route/controller

```
res.render('example', {
   scripts: [assets.js.validation]
  }
)
```

view (using a view engine helper)
just an example of logic

```
each script in scripts
   <script src="{[script}}">
```

This works but I'm wondering what's best practice.

Comment: Why you want to load dynamically?

Comment: I may only want to load an entire js plugin for form validation on pages only with forms. For performance sake. Maybe it's a call that needs to be made, whether it best to just load all scripts and cache them or load only when needed..

Comment: Sometimes simple is the best. You using express. It can support layout. Insert the script path the input form layout file. And using it.

Comment: The script tag wouldn't be at the bottom of the page then, such as after jquery is loaded or a main.js file.